# How to suppress a warning in one line for pylint and Flake8 at the same time

Tags: python, pylint, flake8

I would like to ignore a specific line in static code analysis.

For Flake8, I'd use the syntax `# noqa: F401`.

For pylint, I'd use the syntax `# pylint: disable=unused-import`.

As I am working on a code generation framework, I would like the code to support both linters.
Is there a way to combine both directives such that both of them are correctly detected?

Comment: Perhaps you need a space before the second  `#`

Comment: Thank you @MattClarke. That was a typo in my question. I did mean to include the space around it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

both of these combinations work for me:

```py
import os  # noqa: F401 # pylint:disable=unused-import
import sys  # pylint:disable=unused-import # noqa: F401
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar issue. Having used pylint initially, I had that directive first which caused errors. Reversing the order so that flake8 is first worked for me.

```
# noqa: 501  pylint: disable=unused-argument
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options:

1. Position the `noqa:` command first, followed by the Pylint directive:
   `# noqa: 501 pylint: disable=unused-argument`
2. Position the directives in any order, but make sure they are both preceded by "`#` ":
   `# pylint: disable=unused-argument # noqa: 501`
3. If you also want to have a comment on the same line before the directives you need to add another `#` after the comment:
   `# comment # noqa: 501 pylint: disable=unused-argument`

For me, it's easiest to think of the `#`  as part of the directive and always include it with each one.  Then I don't have to worry about whether or not I need to add an extra one.